# Error Pickling in Python: io.UnsupportedOperation: read

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to learn how to `pickle` and save an object in python. However, when I use the [sample code](http://www.astrobetter.com/python-tip-storing-data/) below I get the following error: `io.UnsupportedOperation: read` which traces back to `favorite_color = pickle.load(f_myfile)`. I cannot find a good explanation of this particular error. What am I doing wrong and how do I correct it?

```
import pickle  # or import cPickle as pickle

# Create dictionary, list, etc.
favorite_color = { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }

# Write to file
f_myfile = open('myfile.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(favorite_color, f_myfile)
f_myfile.close()

# Read from file
f_myfile = open('myfile.pickle', 'wb')
favorite_color = pickle.load(f_myfile)  # variables come out in the order you put them in
f_myfile.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python error message io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901806/python-error-message-io-unsupportedoperation-not-readable)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Change:

```
# Read from file 
f_myfile = open('myfile.pickle', 'wb')
```

to:

```
f_myfile = open('myfile.pickle', 'rb')
```

and you can see the dict obj you've pickled.

Comment: The answer is simple, but sometimes, even veterans need reminders.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use
f = open("myfile.dat", "ab+") or wb+