# Python error message io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Tags: python, file

I have this code:

```
line1 = []
line1.append("xyz ")
line1.append("abc")
line1.append("mno")
    
file = open("File.txt","w")
for i in range(3):
    file.write(line1[i])
    file.write("\n")

for line in file:
    print(line)
file.close()
```

But when I try it, I get an error message like:

```
  File "...", line 18, in <module>
     for line in file:
 
UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Why? How do I fix it?

Comment: Well you do not gave the file read permissions. But it is useless here to do that since the cursor would be located at the end of the file.

Comment: I tried seek function but it didn't work and what do you mean by read permissions?

Answer (score 248, accepted):

You are opening the file as `"w"`, which stands for writable.

Using `"w"` you won't be able to read the file. Use the following instead:

```
file = open("File.txt", "r")
```

Additionally, here are the other options:

```
"r"   Opens a file for reading only.
"r+"  Opens a file for both reading and writing.
"rb"  Opens a file for reading only in binary format.
"rb+" Opens a file for both reading and writing in binary format.
"w"   Opens a file for writing only.
"a"   Open for writing. The file is created if it does not exist.
"a+"  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not exist.
```

Comment: Been comming back every few months with the same error!

Answer (score 34):

### Use `a+` to open a file for reading, writing and create it if it doesn't exist.

> a+ Opens a file for both appending and reading. The file pointer is at
> the end of the file if the file exists. The file opens in the append
> mode. If the file does not exist, it creates a new file for reading
> and writing. -[Python file modes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)

```
with open('"File.txt', 'a+') as file:
    print(file.readlines())
    file.write("test")
```

**Note:** opening file in a `with` block makes sure that the file is properly closed at the block's end, even if an exception is raised on the way. It's equivalent to `try-finally`, but much shorter.

Answer (score 11):

There are few modes to open file (read, write etc..)

If you want to read from file you should type `file = open("File.txt","r")`, if write than `file = open("File.txt","w")`. You need to give the right permission regarding your usage.

**more modes:**

- r. Opens a file for reading only.
- rb. Opens a file for reading only in binary format.
- r+ Opens a file for both reading and writing.
- rb+ Opens a file for both reading and writing in binary format.
- w. Opens a file for writing only.
- you can find more modes in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w)

Answer (score 5):

This will let you read, write and create the file if it don't exist:

```
f = open('filename.txt','a+')
f = open('filename.txt','r+')
```

Often used commands:

```
f.readline() #Read next line
f.seek(0) #Jump to beginning
f.read(0) #Read all file
f.write('test text') #Write 'test text' to file
f.close() #Close file
```

Answer (score 1):

Sreetam Das's table is nice but needs a bit of an update according to w3schools and my own testing. Unsure if this due to the move to python 3.

"a" - Append - will append to the end of the file and will create a file if the specified file does not exist.

"w" - Write - will overwrite any existing content and  will create a file if the specified file does not exist.

"x" - Create - will create a file, returns an error if the file exist.

I would have replied directly but I do not have the rep.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just adding here that, if you use "w" when your intention is to read, it empties the content of the file which ends up giving you a "not readable error" even after you change to "r". I hope that helps someone like me :)

Comment: `open(file, "w")` will empty the file content, but In case of reading an empty file with "r" the "not readable" error will not arise.