# How can i append a list present in file which is in text format?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to append a list present in a text file which is of json formate. But I'm unable to append it. can you help me out...?

```
p=open(r"phbook.txt","at")
l=p.readline().split(",")
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/pyt train/my1/phyton-training/file handelling/phone book save.py", line 2, in <module>
    l=p.readline().split(",")
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Comment: You are opening the file in `at` mode, which is for appending only. You can't read from that file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python error message io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901806/python-error-message-io-unsupportedoperation-not-readable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a text file into a list or an array with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676265/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-list-or-an-array-with-python)