# How to re sub a pattern in a file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a file where I want to apply the following regex pattern to the file and save it.

Below is my code:

```
file = open("/home/hive_db_ddls/abc_db_extract_all_tables.sql","a", encoding='latin-1').read()
for line in file:
  re.sub(r'(TBLPROPERTIES \(.*?\))', r'\1;', file, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python_filter.py", line 4, in <module>
    file = open("/home/hive_db_ddls/abc_db_extract_all_tables.sql","a", encoding='latin-1').read()
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Any suggestion as to why I am receiving this error? I know it should be a small fix but can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: I think you're going to find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901806/python-error-message-io-unsupportedoperation-not-readable)

Comment: Use `"r"` instead of `"a"`, remove `.read()`, make sure you actually modify the line (`re.sub` returns a copy of the string, strings are immutable in Python) - or write into another file.

Comment: didn't answer my question but thanks